# How do I fetch two different record types from the database?

Tags: sql, jooq

I have two tables with a FK relation. What I want is equivalent to:

```sql
select A.*, B.*
from A
join B
    on B.A_ID = A.ID
```

How do I do this efficiently in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)? In the end, I need one instance of `ARecord` and one of `BRecord` per resulting row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
Result<Record> result =
create.select()
      .from(A)
      .join(B).on(B.A_ID.equal(A.ID))
      .fetch();
```

This will fetch `A.*, B.*` (or more precisely, `A.A1, A.A2, ..., A.AN, B.B1, ...`). Now in order to transform `result` into `ARecord` and `BRecord` use the [`Result.into(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#into%28org.jooq.Table%29) method:

```
ARecord a = result.into(A);
BRecord b = result.into(B);
```

Note, that this has known flaws. For instance, if `A.X` is a field that has a corresponding field `B.X` (same field name), `A.X` will hold `B.X`'s value. I have registered a bug report for this: [#1802](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1802)

Comment: Just to let people know.. this issue #1802 has now been marked as closed. So I guess its safe to use